# Как удалить все Items из HorisontalHeader в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Есть таблица `QTableWidget`.
Горизонтальные заголовки заполняются динамически:

```
hdl = QTableWidgetItem("demo_name")

self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(e, hdl)
```

где **`е`** - номер колонки.

`self.takeHorizontalHeaderItem(e)` - удаляет `Item` из заголовка в колонке **`е`**.

Есть какой-нибудь способ очистить весь `HorizontalHeader` без применения циклов (удалить все `Items`)?
**Но при этом не затронуть всё остальное содержимое таблицы.**

Comment: Павел, sorry, а чем плох цикл для очистки всех заголовков?

Comment: @S.Nick пока что циклом и пользуюсь. Но любой цикл - это увеличение времени выполнения программы.
Надеялся, что есть что-то вроде QTableWidget.removeRow (int row), только для очистки содержимого заголовков.

Comment: Павел, нет такого решения. В любом случае надо перебрать каждый `item`. Времени это не занимает нисколько. Попробуйте так: `[self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(
                col, QTableWidgetItem('')) for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount())]`

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо за помощь.
У меня вот так реализовано:
`for col in range(self.my_table.columnCount()):
            self.my_table.takeHorizontalHeaderItem(col)`